# Import All Does Not Import All

Tags: python, tkinter, namespaces, python-import

This `import` statement:

```
from tkinter import *
```

does not import `tkinter.filedialog`. Why it doesn't?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tkinter` is a package, when doing `from tkinter import *` , it would import all the names defined in the `__init__.py` for the `tkinter` package, as well as only modules and subpackages defined in the `__all__` in the `__init__.py` of `tkinter` package.

In my Python 3.4 , there is no `__all__` defined in `tkinter/__init__.py` , hence it does not import any modules (like `filedialog`) from within it.

This is explained in [the documentation -](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)

> The only solution is for the package author to provide an explicit index of the package. The import statement uses the following convention: if a package’s `__init__.py` code defines a list named `__all__` , it is taken to be the list of module names that should be imported when from package import * is encountered.
>
> If `__all__` is not defined, the statement from sound.effects import * does not import all submodules from the package sound.effects into the current namespace; it only ensures that the package sound.effects has been imported (possibly running any initialization code in `__init__.py`) and then imports whatever names are defined in the package. This includes any names defined (and submodules explicitly loaded) by `__init__.py`.

Comment: This seems to contradict this highly rated [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/64130/2228746). _If the __all__ above is commented out, this code will then execute to completion, as the default behaviour of import * is to import all symbols that do not begin with an underscore, from the given namespace._ `filedialog` does not begin with an underscore.

Comment: They are talking about a single module, that is not true for packages (Like I emphasised, `tkinter` is a package, and it does not automatically import modules from within the package (if the `__all__` is not specified). As also very well explained in the documentation that I have linked in my answer.

Comment: Packages are basically directories that can contain other packages/modules . Modules are single `.py` files. If you want to know more about packages, [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) would be a good starting place

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the values imported from a `from <package> import *` depend on the values specified in the `__all__` list for the `__init__` file of that package.

Not being able to import `filedialog` means that it is not contained in the `__all__` list for the `tkinter` `__init__` file.

---

A quick way to evaluate whether a package 'exports' some submodules is to evaluate whether it has an `__all__` attribute after you `import` it. If it does, it will return the available submodules, if not an `Attribute Error` will be raised.

So for example, for a package like `scipy`:

```
import scipy
print(scipy.__all__) # prints all contents.
```